# Select random 4 rows using inner join

Tags: mysql, sql

My table is like this:

```
test_ques
------------------------------
id | ques | skill_id
1  | xyz  | 1
2  | xyz  | 1
3  | xyz  | 1
4  | xyz  | 1
5  | xyz  | 1
6  | xyz  | 2
7  | xyz  | 2
8  | xyz  | 2
9  | xyz  | 2
10 | xyz  | 2
11 | xyz  | 2
12 | xyz  | 3
13 | xyz  | 3
14 | xyz  | 3
15 | xyz  | 3
16 | xyz  | 3
17 | xyz  | 3

skills
------------
id | score
1  | 15
2  | 20
3  | 25
```

I want to select 4 random rows of each skill_id from table test_ques

I was wondering how to do the above and get score from skills table too using inner join.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can store the ids for every skill_id in a string using `GROUP_CONCAT()` ordered by `RAND()`. Then join the subquery with the table selecting first 4 using FIND_IN_SET().

```
select q.*
from (
  select skill_id, group_concat(id order by rand()) as ids
  from test_ques
  group by skill_id
) sub
join test_ques q
  on  q.skill_id = sub.skill_id
  and find_in_set(q.id, sub.ids) <= 4
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/55730/6

Comment: Works perfectly, But can this query be more simpler ?

Comment: @ιηςπεδιδιεζαυπαυ I don't know a simpler way (in one query). If someone finds one, I'd like to see it.

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL, the simplest method is to enumerate the rows for each `skill_id` and then choose four:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             (@rn := if(@s = skill_id, @rn + 1,
                        if(@s := skill_id, 1, 1)
                       )
             ) as rn
      from test_ques t cross join
           (select @s := -1, @rn := 0) params
      order by skill_id, rand()
     ) t
where rn <= 4;
```

Comment: This query returns the same rows everytime, randomly.

Comment: You can seed the random number generator but it should not be returning the same rows.

Comment: @ιηςπεδιδιεζαυπαυ . . . It is an alternative.  This lets you get all the information from the row, instead of just the ids.  If you join back to another table, this should also be faster, because it would allow the `join` to use an index.